# Simple Table Server is not working for multiple thread groups when started STS from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, perf

As per the requirement we need to use STS for handling of test data, we have multiple threadgroup's & we are not supposed to start STS manually

when we start simple table server via JSR223 sampler for a single thread group & STS is not working for the remaining thread groups

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c C:/jmeter/bin/simple-table-server.cmd");

when we start STS for all thread group's & working for random thread group alone, please help on this to make sts as global

how to start STS via jmeter for multi thread group got involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way of starting HTTP Simple Table Server along with JMeter.

As per [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#Getting-Started):

> There are different ways to start the STS:
>
> - with JMeter GUI:
> - with simple-table-server.cmd
> - **on JMeter CLI startup** (Windows : jmeter-n.cmd or Linux jmeter -n) following properties in jmeter.properties file or in user.properties :

So all you need to do is to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeterPlugin.sts.loadAndRunOnStartup=true
jmeterPlugin.sts.port=9191
jmeterPlugin.sts.initFileAtStartup=your-file.csv
jmeterPlugin.sts.initFileAtStartupRegex=false
```

and next time you start JMeter the HTTP Simple Table Server will start and init the CSV file automatically so it will be ready for use.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)